# Using SED with new lines

Tags: json, sed

I have some JSON files where I need to add a `,` after a `}` and  before a new line. The current format of the file looks like this:

```
"some_text"}
{"version":"1.0",
```

This is my current command:

`sed -i '.json' 's/\}\n/\},\n/g' file`.

The regex works when doing search and replace inside the file, but I can't figure out the command line, which I need for bulk edits

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -i 's/}$/&,/' file
```

Sed delimits lines it presents to the pattern space by newlines, therefore the end of a line, using the anchor `$` represents the position before a newline and hence the regexp `}$` represents `}\n`.

Another way is to use:

```
sed -zi 's/}\n/},\n/g' file
```

This slurps the file into memory and the global substitution replaces the match.